# I'm trying to filter a matrix visual based on the number of occurrences

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table full of inter-warehouse transfers that I'm trying to analyze. It looks something like this:

| Product | Quantity | From Warehouse | To Warehouse | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 1 | South | North | 1/1/22 |
| Item 1 | 1 | South | North | 4/1/22 |
| Item 2 | 5 | North | South | 3/1/22 |
| Item 3 | 6 | South | North | 2/1/22 |
| Item 3 | 2 | South | North | 6/1/22 |
| Item 3 | 2 | North | South | 5/1/22 |

I'm trying to see which items we regularly transfer between warehouses, so I have a simple

`Number of Transfers = COUNTROWS()`

measure that is effectively returning the number of transfers for each product as another column in my visual. Item 1 is showing "2", Item 2 is showing "1", etc.

I don't want to see intermittent transfers, so I tried filtering the visual to see all products with a countrows result greater than or equal to a certain number, but when I do, nothing comes up. I've also tried using a calculated column and run into the same issue.

I can do the Top N based on the measure, but that's pretty tedious and feels sloppy. What I'd like is to filter out anything below a given number of transfers. I'm still rather new to all of this and would like to avoid building bad habits if possible.

Does anyone have a better idea how I can go about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re "*I tried filtering the visual to see all products with a countrows result greater than or equal to a certain number*", how exactly did you go about this? Dragging the *Number of Transfers* measure into the Filters pane and setting it to greater than or equal to a certain number should work fine.

Comment: @JosWoolley 

Yes I did. 

I think I figured out the problem; I had a date hierarchy as a secondary row that contained the month and day. The measure must have been picking up the amount of transactions per day and counting those instead of the overall transactions. I removed this hierarchy and everything seems like it's working correctly now. Thank you!